# How do I generate a static website with my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have made a react-app using es6 and jsx. I have a whole components folder and a bunch of css files which I import individually in different components. I also have an index.js file outside the components that imports react-router and has a whole bunch of routing.

I made my app using create-react-app, now I cant find a good tutorial on how to generate a static website. I figured I have to use webpack but apparently create-react-app already has webpack built in, so I'm not so sure where to go from here.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. What does your app do now if it doesn't create a static website? Surely that would have been the key requirement in building the app in the first place. And a whole components folder of what? Components you've written to create a static website? Your question is very very unclear.

Comment: @Andy sorry I'm a beginner but Ill try to explain it a little bit better. To run my app I have to go and run 'yarn start' everytime to launch my react-app, and that puts it on like localhost:8000. I'd rather it not do that, I want to view my website statically(like when I open up index.html I can view it or when I put it on github pages, it can run just fine). Also building my app with yarn(yarn build) and then serving it doesnt work well with react-router, since the routes dont work if I refresh the page.

Comment: React is for building dynamic sites.  If you want to host your site on Github pages, you'll need to build a static site with something like Jekyll.

Comment: No I don't think so. CRA builds are meant to be deployed from a server, from a simple static web server to a node production server. If your site is simple (no gfx, routing) you might be able to get away with editing the path names in the index.html file (`/static/bundle` to `static/bundle`), otherwise I don't think it will work properly.

Comment: Okay thank you, good thing I know better now, I'll just have to use gatsbyJS if I want to build a full on static site with react I guess. Hopefully I can get the app to run with electron, would have been cool if I got ti to work with github pages aswell

Comment: @jmargolisvt you can use gatsbyjs to make a static-site for react, and it has a lot of routing tools available

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GatsbyJS is a great static site generator, but I think it is possible to just use create-react-app to produce a build that can be put on a static server. 
Read the create-react-app documentation about [serving apps with client-side-routing](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)

Normally `yarn build` produces a build directory which contains everything you need to put on a (static) webserver.

There is however a problem when you use React Router with `browserHistory`. A static file server doesn't know how to handle requests for specific pages and hand them over to react router.

You can however use  React Router with `hashHistory`. Use this when you set up ReactRouter:

```
 <Router history={hashHistory}>
```

It will add # strings (hash strings) at the end of your URLs. The router uses the information contained in the string to render the correct components for the particular page that is requested. That way your server doesn't need any configuration and you can just use a static server.

[Here is some info](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md) on the difference between browser history (nice looking url's) and hash history (# sign in the url)

Comment: If using Netlify, add a `_redirects` file in your `public` folder and paste this inside: `/*    /index.html   200`